# Quiero Imprimir con appPOS58AU en python

Tags: python-3.x, windows10

Estoy tratando de usar la impresora de Approx appPOS58AU. Este es el código:

```
from escpos.connections import getUSBPrinter

printer = getUSBPrinter()(idVendor=0x0483,
                          idProduct=0x070b,
                          inputEndPoint=0x81,
                          outputEndPoint=0x02)

printer.text("Hello World")
printer.lf()
```

Como se puede apreciar es muy sencillo, pero me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Escritorio\print.py", line 16, in <module>
    outputEndPoint=0x02)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\escpos\connections.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.initialize()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\escpos\commandset\generic.py", line 463, in initialize
    self.__write(self.__class__.__ESC + '@')
AttributeError: 'USBPrinter' object has no attribute '_Generic__write'
```

Estoy usando Windows10 y estos son los dispositivos USB que tengo conectados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya he solucionado otros problemas iniciales con [la compatibilidad en windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41853951/pyusb-on-windows-7-notimplemented-error-is-kernal-driver-active) e incluso [problemas con pyUSB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773132/pyusb-on-windows-no-backend-available/31332121#) pero ya con este fallo me he topado con un muro y no se como solucionar.

Indicar que la impresora funciona perfectamente y que en Linux me muestra el mismo error.
¿Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Has visto esto: https://github.com/shantanubhadoria/python-printer-escpos/issues/1?

Comment: Grande Patricio, no lo había visto, parece ser que no estaba usando el modulo correcto. Ahora tengo de nuevo el problema con pyusb y windows, pero se que funciona en mis prueba en Linux. A seguir investigando.